# How to communicate between two RecyclerView adapters? I want to send the state of a Boolean from AdapterA to AdapterB

Tags: java, android

In AdapterA I have two global variables

```
int counter = 0;
boolean isAllChecked = false;
```

inside onBindViewHolder I have

```
if (counter == newStatusList.size())
    isAllChecked = true;
```

In AdapterB I need to access `isAllChecked` Boolean variable, if it's true inside AdapterA, I want to change an imageDrawable in AdapterB. My problem here I don't know how to access `isAllchecked` in AdapterB. My app has two adapters and two RecyclerViews.

Comment: How are these 2 adapters used? In the same Activity or 2 different activities?

Comment: They are used in 2 different activities.

Comment: You can use the Activity Result APIs.

Comment: @DarShan As I said I want to communicate between 2 adapter classes not two activities. I want to send boolean isAllChecked from onBindViewHolder of AdapterA to onBindViewHolder of AdapterB. No clickListener is involved here, if all checkboxes are checked inside onBindViewHolder of AdapterA I want the image of   onBindViewHolder of AdapterB be changed.

Comment: You will have to pass the data between Activities since the adapters are set up in 2 different activities. Or you can use a global static variable but I wouldn't recommend that idea.